# Support for Supermicro AOC-SG-i4 in *nix?

Tags: linux, networking, drivers, pci

Long-time reader, first time writer here. Thanks for all the help over the years!

I recently purchased a SuperMicro AOC-SG-i4 from eBay. The seller was a Windows gamer, using the quad port NIC for a LAN server I believe.

I am having quite a bit of trouble trying to use the card in my machine. I was running freeBSD 12.1 for a while, and currently am running Ubuntu 20.04 server. Neither OS can see more than two of the ports, nor can the two visible ports be configured using ethtool. Is this a driver issue, or am I missing something right in front of me and not configuring the card correctly?

Output of `sudo lshw` :

```
dell3010
    description: Space-saving Computer
    product: OptiPlex 3010
    vendor: Dell Inc.
    version: 01
    serial: DT0DJ5J
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=space-saving uuid=44454C4C-5400-1030-8044-C4C04F4A354A
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: 0T10XW
       vendor: Dell Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: A00
       serial: /DT0DJ5J/CN701632BG02P1/
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Dell Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: A21
          date: 05/28/2018
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 8MiB
          capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification netboot uefi
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3470 CPU @ 3.20GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 5a
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3470 CPU @ 3.20GHz
          slot: CPU 1
          size: 2764MHz
          capacity: 3200MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cpuid_fault epb pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms xsaveopt dtherm arat pln pts md_clear flush_l1d cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=4
        *-cache:0
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 36
             slot: CPU Internal L2
             size: 1MiB
             capacity: 1MiB
             capabilities: internal write-through unified
             configuration: level=2
        *-cache:1
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 37
             slot: CPU Internal L1
             size: 256KiB
             capacity: 256KiB
             capabilities: internal write-through data
             configuration: level=1
        *-cache:2
             description: L3 cache
             physical id: 38
             slot: CPU Internal L3
             size: 6MiB
             capacity: 6MiB
             capabilities: internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=3
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 39
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 8GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
             product: KHX1866C10D3/4G
             vendor: Kingston
             physical id: 0
             serial: 6710711C
             slot: DIMM1
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
             product: KHX1866C10D3/4G
             vendor: Kingston
             physical id: 1
             serial: 6710AB1C
             slot: DIMM2
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 09
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=ivb_uncore
          resources: irq:0
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 09
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:26 ioport:2000(size=8192) memory:f0100000-f0afffff ioport:dfb00000(size=4194304)
           *-pci
                description: PCI bridge
                product: PEX 8518 16-lane, 5-port PCI Express Switch
                vendor: PLX Technology, Inc.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: ac
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=pcieport
                resources: irq:16 memory:f0a00000-f0a1ffff ioport:2000(size=8192) memory:f0100000-f09fffff ioport:dfb00000(size=4194304)
              *-pci:0
                   description: PCI bridge
                   product: PEX 8518 16-lane, 5-port PCI Express Switch
                   vendor: PLX Technology, Inc.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: pci@0000:02:01.0
                   version: ac
                   width: 32 bits
                   clock: 33MHz
                   capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
                   configuration: driver=pcieport
                   resources: irq:17 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:f0100000-f05fffff ioport:dfb00000(size=2097152)
                 *-network:0 DISABLED
                      description: Ethernet interface
                      product: 82576 Gigabit Network Connection
                      vendor: Intel Corporation
                      physical id: 0
                      bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                      logical name: enp3s0f0
                      version: 01
                      serial: 00:30:48:da:7a:e4
                      capacity: 1Gbit/s
                      width: 32 bits
                      clock: 33MHz
                      capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                      configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.6.0-k firmware=1.0.1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
                      resources: irq:17 memory:f0100000-f011ffff memory:f0120000-f013ffff ioport:2000(size=32) memory:f0180000-f0183fff memory:dfb00000-dfb1ffff memory:f0184000-f01a3fff memory:f01a4000-f01c3fff
                 *-network:1 DISABLED
                      description: Ethernet interface
                      product: 82576 Gigabit Network Connection
                      vendor: Intel Corporation
                      physical id: 0.1
                      bus info: pci@0000:03:00.1
                      logical name: enp3s0f1
                      version: 01
                      serial: 00:30:48:da:7a:e5
                      capacity: 1Gbit/s
                      width: 32 bits
                      clock: 33MHz
                      capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                      configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.6.0-k firmware=1.0.1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
                      resources: irq:18 memory:f0140000-f015ffff memory:f0160000-f017ffff ioport:2020(size=32) memory:f01c4000-f01c7fff memory:dfb20000-dfb3ffff memory:f01c8000-f01e7fff memory:f01e8000-f0207fff
              *-pci:1
                   description: PCI bridge
                   product: PEX 8518 16-lane, 5-port PCI Express Switch
                   vendor: PLX Technology, Inc.
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: pci@0000:02:02.0
                   version: ac
                   width: 32 bits
                   clock: 33MHz
                   capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
                   configuration: driver=pcieport
                   resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:f0600000-f09fffff ioport:dfd00000(size=2097152)
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 09
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:40 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:50 memory:f7e0a000-f7e0a00f
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:f7e08000-f7e083ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.4.0-54-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 5.04
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: USB hub
                   product: Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@1:1
                   version: 0.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=480Mbit/s
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:51 memory:f7e00000-f7e03fff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: b4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:27
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.4
             version: b4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:28 ioport:d000(size=4096) ioport:f0000000(size=1048576)
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
                logical name: enp6s0
                version: 06
                serial: 78:45:c4:41:1d:19
                size: 1Gbit/s
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 ip=192.168.0.13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
                resources: irq:16 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f0004000-f0004fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:23 memory:f7e07000-f7e073ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.4.0-54-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 5.04
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: USB hub
                   product: Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@2:1
                   version: 0.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=480Mbit/s
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: H61 Express Chipset LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-sata
             description: SATA controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port Desktop SATA AHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             logical name: scsi0
             logical name: scsi1
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: sata msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list emulated
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:39 ioport:f0b0(size=8) ioport:f0a0(size=4) ioport:f090(size=8) ioport:f080(size=4) ioport:f060(size=32) memory:f7e06000-f7e067ff
           *-disk:0
                description: ATA Disk
                product: PNY CS900 240GB
                physical id: 0
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
                logical name: /dev/sda
                version: 0BB3
                serial: PNY1620228576010756C
                size: 223GiB (240GB)
                capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
                configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=aaa7cc84-97ed-477e-bbbf-54d83bc8b4a2 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
              *-volume
                   description: EXT4 volume
                   vendor: Linux
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                   logical name: /dev/sda1
                   logical name: /pny
                   version: 1.0
                   serial: d69a73e4-101a-416a-9a32-8183f38e283c
                   size: 223GiB
                   capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                   configuration: created=2020-11-17 14:04:25 filesystem=ext4 modified=2020-11-18 01:14:46 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime mounted=2020-11-18 01:14:46 state=mounted
           *-disk:1
                description: ATA Disk
                product: Samsung Portable
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
                logical name: /dev/sdb
                version: 1P6Q
                serial: S25NNYAG301953M
                size: 465GiB (500GB)
                capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
                configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=c59a768c-da60-4eee-ae50-7520b970b95a logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
              *-volume:0
                   description: BIOS Boot partition
                   vendor: EFI
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,1
                   logical name: /dev/sdb1
                   serial: 0fd8ff45-3217-4459-b98e-2531291cecd0
                   capacity: 1023KiB
                   capabilities: nofs
              *-volume:1
                   description: EXT4 volume
                   vendor: Linux
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,2
                   logical name: /dev/sdb2
                   logical name: /
                   version: 1.0
                   serial: 9d05a41d-b118-429a-a8ee-35fe70879a8f
                   size: 465GiB
                   capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                   configuration: created=2020-11-17 14:17:31 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2020-11-17 14:30:16 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime mounted=2020-11-17 20:01:52 state=mounted
        *-serial
             description: SMBus
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: driver=i801_smbus latency=0
             resources: irq:18 memory:f7e05000-f7e050ff ioport:f040(size=32)
     *-pnp00:00
          product: PnP device PNP0c01
          physical id: 1
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:01
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 2
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:02
          product: PnP device PNP0b00
          physical id: 3
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=rtc_cmos
     *-pnp00:03
          product: PnP device INT3f0d
          physical id: 4
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:04
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 5
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:05
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 6
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:06
          product: PnP device PNP0501
          physical id: 7
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=serial
     *-pnp00:07
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 8
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:08
          product: PnP device PNP0c01
          physical id: 9
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
```

Comment: Sorry, not sure what happened. The output has been updated, they are under: *-network:0 DISABLED
                      description: Ethernet interface
                      product: 82576 Gigabit Network Connection
                      vendor: Intel Corporation
                      physical id: 0
                      bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                      
Truncated to save space

Comment: Please check in the BIOS for special configurations of Ethernet ports. Sometimes these are used for management functions and may therefore not be available in OSs. Disable all management or other special network functions in the BIOS. Remember what you changed and tell us which change has worked.

Comment: @Ned64 The only relevant options I have are to set Link Speed for the two visible ports. I set them both to each speed (10Mbps half/full, 100Mbps half/full, AutoNeg) and nothing changed. I was able to blink the device lights, and learned which is the first port (farthest from motherboard). I also toggled PXE and WOL options, with no change. The NIC did report as a pro/1000